# How to raise property changed when property in another class is changed? c#

Tags: c#

I have two classes. How can I raise a Property Changed when property of another class is changed? How can I raise property change in the second class if property ActualReading is changed?

Class 1

```
  public class actualmeterreading : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _ID;

    private Int32 _ActualReading;

    public actualmeterreading()
    {
        this._ID = string.Empty;

        this._ActualReading = 0;
    }

    public string ID
    {
        get
        {
            return _ID;
        }

        set
        {
            _ID = value;
        }
    }


    public int ActualReading
    {
        get
        {
            return _ActualReading;
        }

        set
        {
            _ActualReading = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ActualReading");

        }
    }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(String Name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Name));
    }


}
```

class 2

```
public class meterreadingrecords : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _id;

    private actualmeterreading _actualmeterreading;

    public meterreadingrecords()
    {
        this._id = string.Empty;

        this._actualmeterreading = new actualmeterreading();


    }



    public string Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }

        set
        {
            _id = value;
        }
    }



    public actualmeterreading Actualmeterreading
    {
        get
        {
            return _actualmeterreading;
        }

        set
        {

            _actualmeterreading = value;

        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(String Name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Name));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your question?

Comment: Just ensure that **all** properties of your classes report changes and you are finished. Id and Actualmeterreading did not until now, so fix that

Comment: Do you use it for WPF bindings or for what? If it is not for bindings, it seems like a bad design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain the events. For that you need to register the event in the second class, and in the event method you would fire the `RaisePropertyChanged` of the second class

```
public meterreadingrecords()
{
    this._id = string.Empty;

    this._actualmeterreading = new actualmeterreading();

    this._actualmeterreading.PropertyChanged += _actualmeterreading_PropertyChanged


}

private void _actualmeterreading_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RaisePropertyChanged("_actualmeterreading");
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify this solution?